# FOSElasticaBundle: prioritizing followers in user search

Tags: elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I've got symfony2 project set up with elastica via FOSElasticaBundle.
I've got indexing set up for User document(Mongo) using basic settings.
Now when I do a search for users I'd like that search to be prioritized by specified user's followers (to be returned of the top of search).
The followers are stored in separate document (structure: id, follower_id, folowee_id).
What would be the best approach to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after research it seems that only way is to first make a find on follow document, then eventually merge results with find on user. 
First added indexing on follow entity like:

```
    follow:
                mappings:
                     follower: ~
                     followee :
                         type : object
                         properties :
                             id : ~
```

Now I can easily make a search with followee id and followers text string (prefix):

```
    $baseQuery = new \Elastica\Query\Prefix();
    $baseQuery->setPrefix('follower', $text);


    $filter = new \Elastica\Filter\Term();
    $filter->setTerm('id', $id);
    $subquery = new \Elastica\Query\Filtered($baseQuery, $filter);

    $query = new \Elastica\Query();
    $query->setSize(10);
    $query->setQuery($subquery);

    $results =  $service->find($query);
```